# PyQt user logo in center of MDI Area

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, pyqt5, qmdiarea

I have been working on PyQt `QMainWindow` `QMdiArea` Class. I have been able to change the background colour as it is needed for my application.
However, I am unable to add a logo in the centre of the window.

I have tried QBrush but that just insert logo in full `QMdiArea`.
Furthermore, I have tried `paintEvent` overridden method but that seems to not work.

Please find enclosed my code and snapshot of the code output below:

```
# Import necessary libraries
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor, QBrush, QPainter
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QStyleFactory, QWidget, QMainWindow, QMdiArea


class MDI_Window(QMainWindow, QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.centralWidget = QWidget(self)
        self.mdi = QMdiArea()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.mdi)

        self.window_initialize()
        self.show()

    def window_initialize(self):
        title = 'MDI'
        self.setWindowTitle(title)
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("Some_Icon.png"))
        self.setMinimumSize(800, 600)

        self.mdi.setBackground(QBrush(QColor(169, 169, 169)))

        self.showMaximized()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        self.mdi.paintEvent(event)
        self.painter = QPainter(self)
        # For testing logo
        self.painter.drawPixmap(500, 500, 500, 500, QtGui.QPixmap("KDS_Main-Window.png"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Create App with the design
    LMS_App = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    LMS_App.setStyle(QStyleFactory.create('Fusion'))

    a = MDI_Window()
    # Exit application when system is terminated
    sys.exit(LMS_App.exec_())
```

[image: Output of Program with Area Needed for Logo]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot implement the `paintEvent` like that, mostly because a paintEvent *has* to be called by Qt *and* for the specific widget that is being painted. The paint event *must* be implemented in the widget.

The easiest solution is to subclass the QMdiArea:

```
class MdiArea(QMdiArea):
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        # call the base implementation to draw the default colored background
        super().paintEvent(event)
        # create the painter *on the viewport*
        painter = QPainter(self.viewport())
        painter.drawPixmap(500, 500, 500, 500, QtGui.QPixmap("KDS_Main-Window.png"))
```

Note that:

1. you shoud remove the `paintEvent` for the main window, now;
2. as you can see, the painter is called on the *viewport*: this is mandatory for **all** QAbstractScrollArea subclasses;
3. QPainter instances used in a `paintEvent` should *not* be set as instance attributes (as you can see, I didn't use `self.painter`), as the painter must be destroyed at the end of the function, otherwise you'll face performance and drawing issues; you could theoretically avoid this issue by manually calling `painter.end()`, but, since a new QPainter instance is most likely going to be recreated very soon and very often, making it a persistent attribute each time has really no use.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable assistance and explaining the solution in details. Will keep these details in mind for the future.